# Admob on surfaceview

Tags: android, admob, surfaceview

I have an activity which has a surfaceview capturing whole screen. i want to put an admob ad on surfaceview. I found this [link](http://rx-games.com/admob-adverts-on-surfaceview-no-xml-tutorial/) but it does not work. Any idea ?

Comment: The link works fine here. Maybe you mean the provided code doesn't work? In this case, please post your code so we can have a look at it.

Comment: I tried the code at that page. It did not work.

Comment: `It did not work` helps nobody. Post the code you tryed and the Error or Exception-Message you recieved

Comment: have tried it and it doesnt work. Actually there are no errors or logs. dont know what to do next? 
@Kamil: were you able to get this resolved? thanks

Answer (score 9):

In your activity's onCreate:

```
// Add admob ads.
admobView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "YOUR_UNIT_ID");
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
admobView.setLayoutParams(lp);

RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
layout.addView(surfaceView);
layout.addView(admobView);
admobView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

setContentView(layout);
```

IN the example above, "surfaceView" is your surfaceView instance, that you should instantiate like you do today.
Don't forget to call `admobView.destroy()` in your activity's onDestroy.

Comment: Do you mean admobView.destroyDrawingCache()?

Comment: your OnDestroy should include:
 if (admobView != null) {
      admobView.destroy();
    }

Comment: For me (android 2.1) the admobView.destroy(); deas not exist, insteed admobView.destroyDrawingCache(). Is it the same thing?

Comment: You should update your admob sdk to the new one. see:http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/download.html

Comment: That is the one I use... What is the admobView.destroyDrawingCache() then?

Comment: Its not admob specific, but a View method. see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html?is-external=true#destroyDrawingCache()